# More specifics colums width with bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

For some time now I use bootstrap when I have to integrate a design for a website. However the more I used it and the more I feel limited.

With bootstrap you can make two columns with a width of 50% each or even 40% / 60%.

My question is this : Is it possible, with bootstrap, to create two columns with a width of 45 and 55% ?

Even if my english is far for perfect I hope I was clear enough for you to understand my problem.

Comment: Just use custom grid classes. `.col-custom-x { width: 45% }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create custom class , you can do that by extending bootstrap class with you own , for example

```css
.my-custom-class{
@extend .col-md-12;
width:90%
}
```

It will change width but save other attributes which comes from boostrap

Comment: Okay. I thought about it but I wanted to be sure that there were no other way to do it. Thanks :).